# Is an "eye" or a "symbol of eye" important for Judaism?

Tags: parts-of-the-body, symbols-symbology

Eye symbols like above pictures; Are they important for Judaism?

http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v620/FightingFalcon/706px-Eye_of_Horussvg.png
https://t1.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/19/96/66/500_F_19966685_vG4uL8vyAH5qQpZtQRlMUO8rP9RXd6aP.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Symbolism in Judaism is in our actions, not icons. We are [discouraged from having symbols, and many are outright prohibited](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/hamitsvot/lo1-2.htm). We do find significance about certain images, or symbols, and even [certain abilities attributed to them](http://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.65a), but these aren't of a religious nature.

As far as if the eye has any special meaning, it is certainly considered a powerful part of a person and a window to the soul. The [Maharal (Agados Shabbos 118b)](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=14194) explains that the eye is of a loftier level than the other limbs. But this doesn't make the eye a symbol in Judaism.

You might come across this symbol in an amulet but there too, it is there as a mark but not as a holy symbol that we revere. And even as such many take issue with such images.